# DateTime Arithmetic Operations

Tags: vb.net, window

I am trying to perform arithmetic operation on DateTime Object in VB.NET

I have a program in which a subroutine will be used to get the future date of an event by the use of the DateTime Object using it's AddDays Properties. The below is the code Used. It keeps bringing the current minute for the month.

```
    Dim dtToday As DateTime
    Dim dtfuture As DateTime
    dtToday = System.DateTime.Now
    dtfuture = dtToday.AddDays(10)
    MsgBox("Today is :" & dtfuture.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy"))
```

I want it to output the future date in the format ("dd-mm-yyyy") and also show the proper month.

Thank you

Comment: Use 'MM' in place of 'mm'.Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: FYI [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Thank you guys. I got it. that "MM" was the culprit all along

Comment: Vote to close because this is a simple typo (mm instead of MM) and this distinction is clearly explained in the documentation as pointed out by @AndrewMortimer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont really need the variables.

```
  MsgBox(Now.AddDays(10).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy").ToString)
```

Comment: You dont really need the last `.ToString` call. A bit of a habit to call it when using msgbox. `MsgBox(Now.AddDays(10).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))` Will suffice